# One server wrongly redirecting to another when using https

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have a server with two websites. One of them has https and the other has not. My problem is that when I access the server that doesn't have https, It redirects to the server that has it.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and Apache 2.2
I tried finding every place I used rewrite and none of them helped me out.

Here is the config of the first website (that has https)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.first_site.com.br
 ServerAlias www.first_site.com.br
 ServerAdmin info@first_site.com.br
 DocumentRoot /var/www/first_site

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/first_site/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/first_site/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.first_site.com.br
 ServerAlias www.first_site.com.br
 ServerAdmin info@first_site.com.br
 DocumentRoot /var/www/first_site

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/first_site/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/first_site/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/wildSSL/STAR_first_site_com_br.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/wildSSL/STAR_first_site_com_br.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/wildSSL/STAR_first_site_com_br.ca-bundle
SSLProtocol All
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

This is the second site config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.second_site.com.br
 ServerAlias www.second_site.com.br
 ServerAdmin info@second_site.com.br
 DocumentRoot /var/www/second_site

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/exati/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/exati/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, always when I access the first website without https, it automatically redirects to the https version.

Comment: Your first sentence is pretty confusing. Please use http(s)://www.first_site.com.br and http(s)://www.second_site.com.br in your problem description. Also it looks like the rewrite is at the application level, maybe the response headers will show more.

Comment: As @SamK said, this sounds like some feature™ built into the application.  There is also a chance that you are including configs that you haven't noticed.  Check for any `Include` directives in your config and check those for additional rewrites.

Answer (score -1):

Add for the second site

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName www.second_site.com.br
      ServerAlias www.second_site.com.br
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/2731/mix-of-ssl-and-non-ssl-sites-on-apache-2-2/p1

Comment: the OP is trying to stop the redirection, not add more

Comment: @chicks When the op goes to 'https www.second_site.com.br ' it goes to 'https www.first_site.com.br ' This will redirect 'https www.second_site.com.br ' to 'http www.second_site.com.br '

Comment: I still think he was trying to get rid of redirections, not add more

Comment: @chicks Ah I see